# Can't modify print in scalar assignment at -e

Tags: perl

I have some code that I want to use to find duplicates in a sorted file. The (awk-inspired) code looks like:

```
perl -wnla -e 'BEGIN {$previous = -1} $F[1] == $previous ? print $F[1] : $previous = $F[1]' ../VCF/FIN_20.vcf
```

Unfortunately it gives me an error:

```
Can't modify print in scalar assignment at -e line 1, at EOF
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What do I need to do to get it to work?

Ps. the file looks like

```
20  5282284 rs73594467
20  5282299 rs148317959
20  5282336 rs927106
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add parens arround the last instruction:

```
perl -wnla -e 'BEGIN {$previous = -1} $F[1] == $previous ? print $F[1] : ($previous = $F[1])' 
#                                                                here ___^              ___^
```

without them, it is like:

```
($F[1] == $previous ? print $F[1] : $previous) = $F[1]
```

Comment: Better yet, he could use clearer `print $F[1] if $F[1] == $prev; $prev = $F[1]`